# Titles being truncated in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, rubymotion, pixate

Within my app, the title for each navigation controller is set in either `loadView` or `viewDidLoad`

When the view controller is displayed, the title is always truncated - even though the content is not very long ("lessons" in this case).

[image: title is truncated in UINavigationController]

I'm using a custom font - could that case this?

I'm also using PixateFreestyle though I don't know of any bugs with that.

Please tell me there's a solution to this that *isn't* creating a custom titleView label?

Thanks in advance

Comment: calling `setNeedsDisplay` in any of `viewDidLoad` `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`

Comment: "Lessons" title you set in storyboard?

Comment: not using storyboard - it's set programatically in `loadview`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `sizeToFit` on the UILabel custom fonts shouldn't be an issue.

e.g.

```
 @label = UILabel.alloc.initWithFrame(CGRectZero)
 @label.text = "A very long string that shouldn't get truncated"
 @label.sizeToFit
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, `@label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`. That way, if the title is excessively long, the font will be resized in order to allow it to fit. I've never tried this with Pixate, but it works in plain vanilla iOS.